How to verify that gpt-4o model is using prompt caching?
I have deployed a gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model in Azure AI Studio, which has support for prompt caching. It's mentioned that prompt caching is done automatically, but is there any way to verify this for gpt-4o models, as the cached_tokens parameter isn't supported here.
I've tried checking for cached_tokens parameter in the model response, which doesn't exist for gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model. I also tried consecutively sending messages to see if the response time decreases due to prompt caching, but I didn't see any noticeable differences.
